How to add transistion to the image slider?
I'm trying to create an absolute simple image-slider in Vanilla JS.
Got it to work, but have no idea how I could add a transition when the images changing.
Anyone can give me some advice what possibilities I have ?
HTML :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <section id="mainSection">
        <div id="mainDiv">
            <div id="previous" onclick="changeImageBackward()"><i id="arrow" class="fa fa-arrow-left fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            <div id="mainImage">
                <img class="image"  src="#" alt="">
            </div>
            <div id="next" onclick="changeImageForward()"><i id="arrow" class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-5x" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        </div>
    </section>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

CSS:
#mainDiv {
    background-color: rgb(81, 81, 81);
    height: 40vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly
}

#previous {
    background-color: grey;
    height: 80%;
    width: 20%;
    border: solid 1px black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

#mainImage {
    background-color: rgb(108, 108, 108);
    height: 80%;
    width: 50%;
    border: solid 1px black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#next {
    background-color: grey;
    height: 80%;
    width: 20%;
    border: solid 1px black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.image {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
#next:hover, #previous:hover {
    box-shadow: inset  0 0 40px white;
}



JS:
let image = document.querySelector(".image");
const imageSource = ["bee-8978619_1280.jpg", "forest-8371211_1280.jpg", "mushroom-8313142_1280.jpg", "toadstool-8362901_1920.jpg"];
image.src = imageSource[0];
const next = document.querySelector("#next");
let i=0;


function changeImageForward () {
 if (i < 3){  
    i++  
    image.src = imageSource[i] 
    
    } else {
        i = 0
        image.src = imageSource[i];
    }
};

function changeImageBackward (){
if (i > 0) {
    i--
    image.src = imageSource[i]
} else {
    i = 3
    image.src = imageSource[i]
}
};

I don't really know where I could start

Transition of what, exactly? Image position? Opacity? ...? Your current implementation there simply manipulates the src attribute of one single image element - you can't transition anything in this "binary" operation. If you wanted to f.e. fade one image into the other - then you would need two image elements, positioned on top of each other, and then manipulate the opacity of the top one ...

Thank you very much. Im an absolute beginner an thought it would be possible to change the src attribute and combine it with some fade effects. I will try to stack the images and do transitions the way you wrote, thanks

In your ccs you could set up a fade effect for the image and then in js, instead of just swapping the image immediately, add a small delay to allow the transition effect:


function changeImageForward() {
    image.classList.add('fade-out');
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (i < imageSource.length - 1) {
            i++;
        } else {
            i = 0;
        }
        image.src = imageSource[i];
        image.classList.remove('fade-out');
    }, 500); // This matches your CSS transition time
}

function changeImageBackward() {
    image.classList.add('fade-out');
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (i > 0) {
            i--;
        } else {
            i = imageSource.length - 1;
        }
        image.src = imageSource[i];
        image.classList.remove('fade-out');
    }, 500);
}
.image {
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 1;
}

.fade-out {
    opacity: 0;
}




Your code snippet doesn't do anything when we run it. It would be good if you included the rest of @lemond's code so when someone clicks "Run code snippet" it actually works. The alternative is to change your answer to a code sample instead of a snippet.
